# R Shiny - Automatically adding filters with the names of the columns and select values of each column in the data

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I would like to add/remove filters based on column names, i.e., if I select 2 column names, those column names should show `numericRangeInput` or `seletizeInput` or any other based on the class. Can it be done with `conditionalPanel`

Here is what I am trying

```
library(shiny)
nodes = read.csv("data/nodes.csv", header=T, as.is=T)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    
    actionButton("addNode", "Add Node filter", icon=icon("plus", class=NULL, lib="font-awesome")),
    
    uiOutput("filterPage1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  i <- 0
  
  observeEvent(input$addNode, {
    i <<- i + 1
    output[[paste("filterPage",i,sep="")]] = renderUI({
      t4 = class(nodes[,names(nodes)[i]])
      print(t4)
      list(
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            conditionalPanel(
              condition = "t4=='character'",
              column(6, selectInput(paste("filteringFactor",i,sep=""), paste0(names(nodes4)[i],':'),
                                    choices=unique(nodes[,names(nodes)[i]]), selected=NULL,
                                    width="100%")),
              column(6, actionButton(paste("removeFactor",i,sep=""), "",
                                     icon=icon("times", class = NULL, lib = "font-awesome"),
                                     onclick = paste0("Shiny.onInputChange('remove', ", i, ")"))),
                
              condition = "t4=='numeric'",
              column(6, sliderInput(paste("filteringFactor",i,sep=""), paste0(names(nodes4)[i],':'),
                                    choices=unique(nodes4[,names(nodes4)[i]]), selected=NULL,
                                    width="100%")),
              column(6, actionButton(paste("removeFactor",i,sep=""), "",
                                     icon=icon("times", class = NULL, lib = "font-awesome"),
                                     onclick = paste0("Shiny.onInputChange('remove', ", i, ")")))
              
            )
            
          )
        ),
        uiOutput(paste("filterPage",i + 1,sep=""))
      )
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    i <- input$remove
    
    output[[paste("filterPage",i,sep="")]] <- renderUI({uiOutput(paste("filterPage",i + 1,sep=""))})
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the [selectizeGroup-module](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/selectizeGroup-module.html) from library([shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets)).

Comment: We need to manually choose the columns you want to filter in `selectizeGroupUI`. I am looking for an automated way where you can select and filter all.

Comment: That's not correct. `selectizeGroupUI` allows to programmatically select variables (columns) on which to filter (and create according inputs). See the second example "select variables" I linked.

Answer (score 3):

I made an example based on the [link](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/selectizeGroup-module.html) I shared to elaborate on my comments (yours isn't reproducible):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tools)
library(datasets)

d <- data(package = "datasets")
dataset_is <- sapply(gsub(" .*$", "", d$results[,"Item"]), function(x){is(get(x))[1]})
DFs <- names(dataset_is[dataset_is == "data.frame"])

filterParams <- function(vars){
  setNames(lapply(vars, function(x){
    list(inputId = x, title = paste0(tools::toTitleCase(x), ":"), placeholder = "...")
  }), vars)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,
      selectInput("dataset", label = "Select dataset", choices = DFs),
      tags$h3("Filter data with selectize group"),
      uiOutput("panelProxy"),
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  selected_dataset <- reactive({
    DF <- get(input$dataset)
    setNames(DF, gsub("\\.", "_", names(DF))) # avoid dots in inputId's (JS special character)
  })
  
  vars_r <- reactive({
    input$vars
  })
  
  res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters",
    data = selected_dataset,
    vars = vars_r
  )
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(res_mod())
    res_mod()
  })
  
  output$panelProxy <- renderUI({
    available_vars <- names(selected_dataset())
    panel(
      checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId = "vars",
        label = "Variables to use:",
        choices = available_vars,
        selected = available_vars,
        inline = TRUE
      ),
      selectizeGroupUI(
        id = "my-filters",
        params = filterParams(available_vars)
      ),
      status = "primary"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: `selectizeGroupUI` is kind of generalizing all class types. It would be if it could distinguish between "categorical/character" class and "numeric" class type and create `numericRangeInput` and 'selectizeGroupInput` for categories. `selectizeGroupUI` is always shows everything rather based on `checkboxGroupInput`

Comment: @BigDataScientist you could use `?type.convert()` to process the selections made via `selectizeGroupUI`.

Comment: PS: `selectizeGroupUI` doesn't use `checkboxGroupInput` at all.